# Raster layer doesn't match vector layer

Tags: qgis, rasterization

I convert vector layer to raster layer using Geo Units. But result of rasterization doesn't match the source vector layer. Why is it hapenned? The layers have same CRS. Is it because pixel size?

I also tried to rasterize layer using pixels instead of Geo units but I've got a square grid.
Are there any ways to create accurate raster layer (or a little bit lower than source vector layer) or may be to extract new boundary of raster layer? My main problem is that raster layer in some places is more than source vector layer.
I also tried to create vector layer grid before rasterizing but my vector layer is very complicated and I can't to select something in vector grid.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick here is that in the Rasterize dialog, the "optional" `Output extent` input need to be set to match the original vector layer's extent. Click on the icon at the right end of the input box, select *Calculate from Layer*, and select your input layer. No idea why it works this way, though.

[image: Screenshot showing the described settings]

Comment: Amazing! Thank you!