# QGIS rasterize with field as value, outcome only captures part of values in the field

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, rasterization

I have a vector file with multiple polygons with a column named all_cert. I want to rasterize this data but everytime I do, the resulting raster file only contains pixels with values for certain areas of my original polygon file. The majority of all the pixels get the value 0 even though they shouldn't.

I really have no idea why only parts of field values gets rasterized and the rest is left with a 0. I get no error messages during the process. I have tried using QGIS raster to vector and python rasterio and I get the same result. I have updated to the latest version of QGIS. I have tried changing the rasterization parameters a little. Always the same result.

Which makes me belive there is something wrong with the file but it works as it should as a vector and shows all the information correctly then. This vector file is a merged file between several other vector files. The areas that has values more than 0 after being rasterized are two separate vector files before the merge. But I don't see how this would affect the result after they have been merged.

What is going wrong with my file or field attribute?
[image]

```
# Fill null values with -999
vector['All_cert'].fillna(-999, inplace=True)
# Convert values to integers
vector['All_cert'] = vector['All_cert'].astype(int)
[![enter image description here][1]][1]
# create tuples of geometry, value pairs, where value is the attribute value to burn
geom_value = ((geom, value) for geom, value in zip(vector.geometry, vector['All_cert']))

print('Rasterizing..')
# Rasterize vector using the shape and transform of the raster
rasterized = features.rasterize(geom_value,
                                out_shape = raster.shape,
                                transform = raster.transform,
                                all_touched = True,
                                fill = -999,   # background value
                                merge_alg = MergeAlg.replace,
                                dtype = int32)
```

Comment: Have you tried smaller resolutions?  Does the SAGA Polygons to Raster tool also fail?  I assume you have checked the geometry and topology of your vector layer.

Comment: Can you perhaps post sample data for us to check? Also, in QGIS Rasterize, set the Output extent to match that of the input vector layer. I just discovered that leaving it not set can lead to some problems, [see this post](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/475831/raster-layer-doesnt-match-vector-layer).

Comment: Hi @John I tried a smaller resolution and there is still no change and now after your suggestion I also tried the SAGA tool but then the task fails. I'm not sure why. I have checked the geometry and topology. Thank you for your suggestions though I appreciate it.

Comment: @crafter6029 Thanks for your suggestion, I tried setting the output extent to match the vector layer, no change in the output still. In my vector file I have a little more than 200 000 features and 170 000 of them are null. My vector file that I am trying to rasterize is the result of 6 merged vectors. Individually I can rasterize each file, the fault happens after they have been merged and then for some reason the rasterization doesn't work anymore. Maybe this gives you any more ideas?

Comment: @Evelina you could try clipping a part of the merged vector, say 10 000 features and see if you can rasterize that - if yes, then the issue could be size related. Or you could work around the issue by rasterizing the individual vector files and then merging the rasters.

Comment: When you say the topology was checked does that include the rule of no overlapping polygons?  I would think overlapping polygons would create a problem for assigning an attribute for the tool and you would need to decide ultimately how you wanted that to be handled.  Since you can rasterize each file,  I'd go with crafter6029's suggestion of rasterizing them and merging the results, and if there are overlaps decide how you want those to be handled.